# Nginx reverse proxy to NodeJS App causing 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

I am setting up nginx so that I can access my API built using express through a url like - example.com/api

Here is my nginx config

```
upstream appfrontend {
    server localhost:9008 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream api {
server localhost:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name hospoline.com www.hospoline.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name example.com; # replace this with your domain

    root /var/www/html/example-certbot-webroot;

    # The public and private parts of the certificate are linked here
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location /.well-known {
        root /var/www/html/example;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://appfrontend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 900s;
    }
    location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

When I visit my site example.com the front end loads perfectly.

When I visit **example.com/api/fetch_doctors, I get a 502 bad gateway error.**

My API is working fine in localhost. When I send a request to localhost:3001 on my local computer, I get the list of doctors.

Both my front end server and backend server are run using forever.

I am really lost and breaking my head about this for one full day. I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Any help in the right direction would be great! Thank you all!

Comment: Is the nodejs application  running properly?

Comment: Yes it is. I am sure because my front end loads and is able to communicate with the backend. From the front end I can access the API by sending requests to localhost:3001/fetch_doctors. But I need the API to be accessible by other applications which is why I am doing this!

Comment: Batman you were right! Made a really stupid mistake! The front end was working because it was sending requests to my local server which was running. I never realised the node js process had crashed. That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much.